# Using twig, how can I create equal length columns of entry names?

Tags: symfony, twig, octobercms, craftcms

E.g.

Column one:
Apples Apricots Avocados Bananas

Column two :
Boysenberries Blueberries Carrot Cherry

Column three :
Cantaloupe Clementine Cucumbers Dates

This is for 12 entries but as the list grows the entries in the columns will update so there is an even number in each of the three columns in the order that they are in the CP

Eg if there were 16 entries the columns would be

Column one:
Apples Apricots Avocados Bananas Boysenberries

Column two :
Blueberries Carrot Cherry Cantaloupe Clementine

Column three :
Cucumbers Dates Elderberry Eggfruit

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you just use `CSS` for this? `ul` has a style `columns`

```css
ul {
  columns: 3;
  -webkit-columns: 3;
  -moz-columns: 3;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>alpha</li>
  <li>beta</li>
  <li>charlie</li>
  <li>delta</li>
  <li>echo</li>
  <li>foxtrot</li>
  <li>golf</li>
  <li>hotel</li>
  <li>india</li>
  <li>james</li>
  <li>kilo</li>
  <li>limo</li>
  <li>mama</li>
  <li>november</li>
  <li>papa</li>
 </ul>
  
 <hr />
  
 <ul>
  <li>alpha</li>
  <li>beta</li>
  <li>charlie</li>
  <li>delta</li>
  <li>echo</li>
  <li>foxtrot</li>
  <li>golf</li>
  <li>hotel</li>
  <li>india</li>
  <li>james</li>
  <li>kilo</li>
  <li>limo</li>
  <li>mama</li>
  <li>november</li>
  <li>papa</li>
  <li>alpha</li>
  <li>beta</li>
  <li>charlie</li>
  <li>delta</li>
  <li>echo</li>
  <li>foxtrot</li>
  <li>golf</li>
  <li>hotel</li>
  <li>india</li>
  <li>james</li>
  <li>kilo</li>
  <li>limo</li>
  <li>mama</li>
  <li>november</li>
  <li>papa</li>  
 </ul>
```